# SwiftUI - Simple Firestore Query - Display Results

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui

Ok, I'll preface this with the fact that I'm new to SwiftUI and programming. I'm a UX Designer. However, I'm trying to run a simple Firestore query and return the results to a list.

I've been able to write a function that writes the results to the console successfully, but I have no idea how to access the information that's within the function so that I can use it within the main view of the page.

I've started a simple view so that I can just focus on displaying Firestore data in a list. Here's my barebones code currently.

```
import SwiftUI
import FirebaseFirestore

struct FestivalListFB: View {

    let db = Firestore.firestore()

    func getVenues() {
        let db = Firestore.firestore()
        db.collectionGroup("Venues").getDocuments() {(querySnapshot, err) in
            if let err = err {
                print("Error getting documents \(err)")
            } else {
                for document in querySnapshot!.documents {
                    guard let venueEntry = document.get("venueTitle") as? String else {
                        continue
                    }
                    print(venueEntry) 
                }
            }
        }
    }



    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            List(0 ..<5) { item in
                Text("Hello, World!")
            }
        }.onAppear(perform: getVenues)
    }
}
```

Console displays:

"Refreshment Outpost
Holiday Sweets & Treats
Fife & Drum Tavern
L'Artisan des Glaces
Shi Wasu
...etc"

And of course, the body only displays "Hello World" 5 times within a list. How would I go about accessing the values in "venueEntry" so that I can display it within the list element?

I've included a image of my Firestore data structure as well. Ideally, I'd like to display the venues grouped by the "venueArea" they are located in.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For easier use, i created a model for you venue. See the below snippet how you can show your data in your View.

Your model:

```
class VenueObject: ObservableObject {
    @Published var venueID: String
    @Published var venueTitle: String
    @Published var venueArea: String

    init(id: String, title: String, area: String) {
        venueID = id
        venueTitle = title
        venueArea = area
    }
}
```

Your View:

```
struct FestivalListFB: View {

    @State var data: [VenueObject] = []

    let db = Firestore.firestore()

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ForEach((self.data), id: \.self.venueID) { item in
                Text("\(item.venueTitle)")
            }
        }.onAppear {
            self.getVenues()
        }
    }

    func getVenues() {
        // Remove previously data to prevent duplicate data
        self.data.removeAll()
        self.db.collectionGroup("Venues").getDocuments() {(querySnapshot, err) in
            if let err = err {
                print("Error getting documents \(err)")
            } else {
                for document in querySnapshot!.documents {
                    let id = document.documentID
                    let title = document.get("venueTitle") as! String
                    let area = document.get("venueArea") as! String

                    self.data.append(VenueObject(id: id, title: title, area: area))
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Tobias, that has helped me tremendously in understanding.

Comment: How would I go about avoiding the appending? I noticed that every time the view loads it adds another iteration of the results below the initial results?

Comment: @Jason The only thing you have to do is to removeAll() at the start of fetching your data. So first empty your data array, then append everything from the firebase. This will make sure you only get your data shown once :-)

Comment: Thank you so much for this @TobiasHesselink !! I have seen so many explanations on how to use get.Documents() from the firestore but had struggled to find a simple example that didn't get carried away with repositories and alike. I know all of that extra stuff is important and I will proceed to do that soon but when you are learning it's nice to stick to the basics and get something running.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just:

```
import SwiftUI
import FirebaseFirestoreSwift
struct ContentView: View {
    @FirestoreQuery(collectionPath: "Venues") var venues: [Venue]
    var body: some View {
        List(venues) { venue in
            Text(venue.venueTitle)
                .font(.headline)
            + Text(" \(venue.venueArea)")
                .foregroundColor(.secondary)
        }
    }
}

struct Venue: Codable, Identifiable {
    @DocumentID var id: String?
    var venueTitle: String
    var venueArea: String
}
```